# Lotus Notes 4.6.7a API or protocol

Tags: lotus-notes

I want to make a program which automatically gets some data from one of the lotus notes database. 
I have to implement connection to the server, with login and password, to request the needed database and get what I want. But without using the Lotus Notes program, make a C++ program instead for this purpose.

The version s v4.6.7a. Old one. Who knows where to get the data protocols or may be API for C language?

Comment: IBM knows... if you have Lotus Notes then IBM can point you to APIs etc. on how to interact with it...

Comment: Is 4.6.7 the client version, or the server version?

Comment: Notes 4.6.7? Wow. That's from the beginning of my development career. Any chance they're still running Windows 95?

Comment: @DavidNavarre No they are running o windows xp and windows 7 :)

Comment: @maximus That's what I figured. I assume they complain about how slow and ugly Notes is, not realizing their system is 15 years old. It reminds me of the Notes implementation at the US Department of State - they were replacing the teletype system (for "cables" sent from embassies and such to Washington) with Notes and the requirements insisted on keystroke-for-keystroke duplication of the teletype system and the exact same interface. Needless to say, it was just as slow and user-unfriendly as the old system it duplicated. So, State Department employees all thought Notes sucked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a JAR for the Java  language that implements all the features you request.
It's NCSO.jar and it's located in the Louts Notes installation directory.

As an alternative you can use NotesSQL and access its data through ODBC.

Comment: i have only this JAR files there: rt.jar notes.jar icsclass.jar i18n.jar

Comment: Version 4.6.7 is really an old one... Maybe I don't remember well. You can use a NCSO.jar from a newer client or from the Domino server installation directory instead.

Comment: I can't reinstall Lotus Notes for a newer version. If the features can be implemented by using notes.jar or something else, then is there any documentation for my version?

Comment: Have you got a notes\domino\java directory?

Comment: I think you notes.jar isn't enough but I've got no environment to try it out. Try to inspect jar content: if you find Session, Database, View DocumentCollection and Document classes then you can do the job.

Comment: I have them! But still need some documentation on them.

Comment: You can obtain a Session from a NotesFactory or something similar providing user, pwd and server information. The connect to database with Session.getDatabase() and from database read/write Documents.

Comment: Bob Balaban recently posted the content from his book about Java programming for Notes on his blog.  The book came out between the releases of 4.6 and 5.0, so it is probably the best documentation you will find.  Here is a link:  http://www.bobzblog.com/tuxedoguy.nsf/dx/programming-domino-with-java-final-flush

Comment: The link above is useful. But after trying the code written there i get exception on execution of NotesThread.sinitThread()  UnsatisiedLinkError: no lsxbe in java.library.path. Do you know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

You can download [Lotus C/C++ API toolkits](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/documentation/capi/) from the [developerWorks Lotus Developer Toolkits page](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/downloads/toolkits.html#notesdomino).

Comment: I couldn't find there the API for 4.6 version. How do you think is it ok to use version 6.0 instead?

Comment: 4.6 is about 16 years old. I would guess, that the V 6 sould work too.